# RabbitMQ internet connexion handling

Tags: android, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ tutorial is easy about this :

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
connection_ = connectionFactory.newConnection();
channel...
channel.basicPublish...
```

however, how does it work on a smartphone for instance ? The internet connection could be not available, or available at connection time, and unavailable at publish time

Does rabbitmq handles everything for us ? (Im on Android if it matters)

Comment: It will disconnect and you will probably have to implement a reconnection protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read here :
https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html section "Connection Failures",you have to handler the connection fail and reconnect the client, or use some ready ha client.

**EDIT:**

Since the version 3.3.0 you can set the ConnectionFactory parameter:

```
...
connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
connectionFactory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
...
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941644/rabbitmq-surviving-a-consumer-disconnection-using-defaultconsumer)