# RabbitMQ - surviving a consumer disconnection using DefaultConsumer

Tags: rabbitmq

using java client QueueingConsumer I wrote the following code to assist consumer recovery

```
while (true) {
   try{
      .. create connection
      .. create channel & queue
      while (true) {
             final QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
             ....
      } catch {
          handleException()
      }
}
```

And every time I restarted rabbit it survived cause it created the connection from start.
Now, I understand I should be working with DefaultConsumer.
So I have this method

```
public void handleDelivery(...) throws IOException {
}
```

and my problems are :

1. I cant catch the exception inside and recreate the connection
2. This only recovers when the ack fails. What if it fails in another stage of the process?
   How should I recover these fails?
   Thanks.

Comment: That’s a good question, first code works because it’s all synchronous and blocking , and you can catch the error  then decide. 
The second one you have to change a way to dev your system ... more event-driven :)!, you should use the connection shutdown event to understand the connection state.  
Anyway, if you won’t receive an answer I will prepare an simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update to version 3.3.0 of the Rabbit Java Client. Finally, they have added support for reconnection and re-declaration of your topology.

You just need to set this when setting up the `ConnectionFactory`:

```
...
connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
connectionFactory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
...
```

Comment: hello hector, I haven't tried it yet. So, does it recover also the channels state?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I have created this code to test it: http://pastebin.com/xKzbppSX I was able to consume all the messages and not lose a single one after forcing to close my connection.

Comment: Thanks hecktor!! thanks for the good reference. BTW: I wonder what are Rabbit Lyra benefits now.

Comment: @rails The main thing is that the Java amqp-client recovery only kicks in when a connection fails. Lyra will recover from any failure, including Channel or Consumer failures, and of course it provides flexible RecoveryPolicies for dictating how recovery should proceed.

Comment: @Jonathan, Java amqp-client can recover queues, exchanges, bindings, and consumers except client.

Comment: @JohnSmith Last I checked, only connection errors trigger recovery. Also https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#cache-pitfalls